# How can I cleanup Visual Studio SP1 installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I installed Visual Studio 2010 and applied SP1 and then my HDD died and I had to uninstall and install Visual Studio.

Now trying to apply SP1 again however the installer gets stuck. When I check the logs, this is the error :

> INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE

It's trying to check the disk space in a non-existent volume (D:) in this case instead of the new volume of installation and gets in a recursive loop.

The following repeats itself thousands times in the logs

```
Returning IDCANCEL. INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE [Out of disk space -- Volume: 'D:'; required space: 7,090 KB; available space: 0 KB. Free some disk space and retry.]
Returning IDNO. INSTALLMESSAGE_USER [Are you sure you want to cancel?]
Returning IDCANCEL. INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE [Out of disk space -- Volume: 'D:'; required space: 7,090 KB; available space: 0 KB. Free some disk space and retry.]
Returning IDNO. INSTALLMESSAGE_USER [Are you sure you want to cancel?]
Returning IDCANCEL. INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE [Out of disk space -- Volume: 'D:'; required space: 7,090 KB; available space: 0 KB. Free some disk space and retry.]
Returning IDNO. INSTALLMESSAGE_USER [Are you sure you want to cancel?]
Returning IDCANCEL. INSTALLMESSAGE_OUTOFDISKSPACE [Out of disk space -- Volume: 'D:'; required space: 7,090 KB; available space: 0 KB. Free some disk space and retry.]
Returning IDNO. INSTALLMESSAGE_USER [Are you sure you want to cancel?]
```

I tried Microsoft Fix it for cleanup uninstall but didn't work, it's still same.

What's the way to actually clean up after Visual Studio SP1 so it won't look at the previous installation directory?

Answer (score 0):

The correct document is actually obtained from the ReadMe of the original SP1 [download site](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210711):

See:

- 2.2. Uninstalling, and

  - 2.2.1. If Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 is uninstalled, Visual Studio 2010 must be reinstalled to restore certain components

"Read 2.2.1. in this readme for instructions about how to reinstall Visual Studio 2010 after SP1 is uninstalled. After Visual Studio 2010 is reinstalled, reapply SP1."

I think this may fix your issue with the service pack.

Comment: I've uniinstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who gets this error in the future, I had this problem and solved it:

1) Though there may be no hard drive volume D:, if you see this, you likely have an optical drive with that drive letter assigned (which is why it can find D, but there are 0 bytes free). Temporarily reassign the optical drive to another letter, and the installation should continue.

2) While you're at it, you may want to get a third-party tool like Registry Workshop so that you can search for all Visual Studio 2010 keys that have a path pointing to drive D:, and delete them.

3) Write to Microsoft and point how how ridiculous it was for them to a) abuse the registry for things they should have used the AppData folder for, b) not create proper tools to clear all registry keys for a product (their existing standalone uninstaller will leave practically all keys untouched), c) write installers which swallow error messages entirely without alerting the user, forcing them to dig through log files, and d) the registry system as a whole.